# Push in array not reactive in HTML

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I remove a comment on my HTML var {{selecionados}} selected from, and I click on the list of names is all fine, but when HTML retreat or comment on again no longer works.

```
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/raphaelscunha/9cwztvzv/1/embed/"></script>
```

Comment: You should copy the code to your question as well, since links don't survive over time and other people won't be able to find the code through a search.

Answer (score 0):

Vue.js will only update your view when a property within the `data` object is *changed*, not when a new property is added. (See [Change Detection Caveats](http://vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) in the Vue.js guide)

If you want it to react when `ativo` is set to `true`, make sure the property exists beforehand.
Try something like this when you're initializing your `Vue` object:

```
atores: [
  { name: 'Chuck Norris', ativo: false},
  { name: 'Bruce Lee', ativo: false },
  { name: 'Jackie Chan', ativo: false },
  { name: 'Jet Li', ativo: false}
]
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dtbgc8b7/1/)